# Makefile not picking up dependencies when in variable

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I'm having a file structre like

```
/ 
 |- Makefile
 |- libs
    |- lib1
    |- lib2
 |- src
    |- file.cpp
```

I have one top-level Makefile which includes a Rules.mk file within every subdirectory. The src file rule depends on lib1 and lib2, which get built by the makefile as well.

now I have a target like:

```
# predefined rule
COMP := gcc -o $@ $< $(FLAGS)

file.o: OBJS := libs/lib1/lib1.o libs/lib2/lib2.o
file.o: file.cpp $(OBJS)
    $(COMP) $(OBJS)
```

when building the stuff (default target is file.o) it complains about the libraries not being there. When I add an echo to the file.o task and print out `$(OBJS)` it prints out all the libs I've assigned to it, but make doesn't trigger building them.

When I replace the variable $(OBJS) in the dependencies with the filenames, it triggers the builds and then obviously finds the required libraries.

I thought it might have something to do with the .SECONDARYEXPANSION, but it shouldn't as I'm not using any delayed variables.

Thanks in advance!

regards
Chris

PS: the project is on Github anyway, the following file contains the Rule I'm talking about: https://github.com/janhancic/CHIC/blob/242c0ceee558c2eb4b21fe73e94a9ab5f3fe0b49/src/Rules.mk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this.  The documentation for GNU make is very clear: target-specific variables are available ONLY *inside* the recipe.  They are not available in the target or prerequisite lists.  In the prerequisite list make will expand `$(OBJS)` the value of the global variable `OBJS`, or the empty string if that doesn't exist; NOT to the target-specific variable value.

However, I don't understand why you write this:

```
file.o: OBJS := libs/lib1/lib1.o libs/lib2/lib2.o
```

when you could just write this:

```
file.o: libs/lib1/lib1.o libs/lib2/lib2.o
```

and have it work fine?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that explains everything! :)
I've looked at the man page for about 2 hours yesterday, but haven't seen that... it probably was too late to concentrate

Yeah, that's what I did to work around it, but I set a TGT specific variable for linking and I also want the task to depend on it, that's why I wanted to use the target specific variable in the dependencies as well

Comment: The man page is just a quick reference guide.  It doesn't contain everything there is to know about using GNU make: it would be far too long.  You have to look at the GNU make user's manual.  That should be available to you from wherever you got the make program, or you can read it online http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/  Note that the online version is for the latest release; there may be things documented there that your version doesn't support, if it's older.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "set a target-specific variable for linking and I also want the task to depend on it"; can you edit your question to show an example of this?  Because the complete set of prerequisites is available to the recipe using automatic variables: you don't need to assign a variable separately for them.  But maybe I just don't get it.  However we can only suggest solutions to questions that are actually asked :-).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what MadScientist already said,

```
COMP := gcc -o $@ $< $(FLAGS)
```

uses *immediate* assignment, which evaluates the expression on the right immediately, the result being essentially `COMP := gcc -o $(FLAGS)`. Use the *deferred* assignment instead:

```
COMP = gcc -o $@ $< $(FLAGS)
```